# Cannot store a large double into Oracle (ORA-01426: numeric overflow)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

In my Oracle (Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production), this query fails:

```
select 9.1E+136 from dual;
```

It tells me something like: ORA-01426: numeric overflow (I've tried 9.1E136, 9E136 as well). Which is really strange, since numbers up to about 2E+308 should be supported (http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefsqljdoubleprecision.html).

I've bumped into this problem from an Hibernate application, which maps a double field to FLOAT with default precision of 126 (Should be more than enough (http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj27281.html).

Anyone any idea? Depends on some configuration parameter? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please note that although Oracle own Java DB, it's a completely different database platform to Oracle's own database. Therefore you should not assume the documentation applying to Java DB also applies to the Oracle database.

Comment: Right, but it's unclear whether that page is about Oracle, Java, or JDBC. Whatever the case, it's not very good that they don't stick to the IEEE standard and they confuse users with contradicting documentation.

Comment: the "javadb" right in the pathname of the link to the documentation you've pointed at should be a big clue, though! Admittedly, the page itself isn't tremendously helpful in indicating what product it's documenting! Also, they do stick to the IEEE standard with the floating point numbers - see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i22294

Comment: Also, the Oracle database was designed before the IEEE 754 standard was introduced, so is it any wonder that they chose to add additional datatypes to support it, rather than re-engineer their existing code?

Comment: I guess so, yet, it's natural for a user of present times to assume binary_double would be the default and the 'd' postfix (see my answer) is not needed. Instead, I've wasted half a day trying to debug an Hibernate application and now I don't exactly know how to deal with the issue ('binary double' in the JPA annotation isn't compatible with H2, which we use for testing).

Comment: You know what they say about "assume"! It's all there to be read about in the documentation - providing you look up the correct documentation, of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found a solution: there is the binary_double type, numbers like that are cast to it when a d is appended to their value:

```
select 9.1E+136d from dual; # works
select 9.1E+136 from dual; # doesn't work

create table test ( no binary_double primary key );
insert into test values ( 9.2E136d ); # OK 
insert into test values ( 9.3E136 ); # Fails
```

So needlessly stupid...

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle documentation states that:

Positive numbers in the range 1 x 10-130 to 9.99...9 x 10125 with up to 38 significant digits

You are overflowing the number data type.

[Numeric Types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209)

Comment: which contradicts both the reality and other links from Oracle I've reported in my question. That page mentions limits for number() type, binary_double is the one compatible with the IEEE standard (i.e., the decent one), but using it is awkward. The problem comes from the fact that software using this standard (eg Java) goes beyond these limits, but Hibernate do the wrong mapping.